# When the $\angle BPA$ is greatest that $P$ is point on $x$-axis?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]
Likewise this picture, the angle $\angle BPA$ isn't greatest when $AP+PB$ is least. Than, when the $\angle BPA$ is greatest?I think that $\tan\alpha \tan\beta$ is minimum when $\alpha=\angle GPB,\beta=\angle APF$. Is this right?

Comment: Are you familiar with the inscribed angle theorem?

Comment: @Arthur I want to use it but it is hard to use

Comment: If I am not wrong, the answer is not nice: $116.1166...^{\circ}.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg How did you get that?

Comment: By the law of cosines.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg How did you know when is minimum?

Comment: @user366725 Presumably by differentiating and setting the derivative equal to $0$?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $A$ and $B$ lie on the same side of the $x$-axis.

Take a point $C$ on the $x$-axis, and draw the circle going through $A, B$ and $C$. If there are points of the $x$-axis inside this circle, then any of those points will make a larger angle than $\angle ACB$. This is a corollary of the inscribed angle theorem, which says that any point on the circumference of the circle (on the same side of $AB$) gives the *same* angle. Thus for any point $D$ of the circle *below* the $x$-axis, any point of the $x$-axis inside the triangle $\triangle ADB$ will give a point on the $x$-axis yielding a larger angle than $\angle ACB$.

So what you want is the circle going through $A$ and $B$ which touches the $x$-axis, and the point where this circle touches the $x$-axis is your $P$. If the line $AB$ is parallel to the $x$-axis, then the solution is easy. If not, then find the point $Q$ where $AB$ intersects the $x$-axis. By the power of a point, we have $|PQ|^2 = |AQ|\cdot |BQ|$. This should be enough to locate $P$, except you get two solutions. These two solutions are the two local maxima for the angle $\angle APB$, one on either side of the line $AB$. The one of these which lies "below" the line is the global maximum (unless $AB$ is vertical, in which case the two solutions are, of course, equivalent).

In your example, as far as I can see, we have $A = (-6, 8)$ and $B = (4, 3)$, meaning $Q = (10, 0)$. This gives
$$
|AQ|\cdot |BQ| = \sqrt{256 + 64}\cdot\sqrt{36 + 9}\\
= \sqrt{14400} = 120
$$
So $P = (10-\sqrt{120}, 0)$ (while the solution $(10+\sqrt{120}, 0)$ is discarded). By the law of cosines, we get
$$
\cos\angle APB = \frac{|AP|^2 + |BP|^2 - |AB|^2}{2|AP|\cdot |BP|}\\
= \frac{(\sqrt{120}- 16)^2 + 8^2 + (\sqrt{120} - 6)^2 + 3^2 - 10^2 - 5^2}{2\sqrt{(\sqrt{120}- 16)^2 + 8^2}\sqrt{(\sqrt{120} - 6)^2 + 3^2}}\\
\approx -0.0182
$$
yielding $\angle APB\approx 91.04^\circ$

Comment: Your answer said maximum $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ but in picture's case, maximum angle is $91.×××××...$

Comment: When did I say max $90^\circ$?

Comment: Hmm..... I thought follow your step and location of p is when circle touches x axis....

Comment: @user366725 Yes. And if, say, $A = (-10, 1)$ and $B = (10, 1)$, then the circle going through $A$ and $B$ which touches the $x$-axis touches the $x$-axis at the origin $O$. I am not claiming that $\angle AOB <90^\circ$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much to answer my question.